# a surpring thing about the hook formula

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, representation-theory

The [hook formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) gives the dimension of the irreducible representations of the symmetric group $S_N
$.

I note that this is an amazing formula even from the point of view of a middle school student.

It is too obvious at all the formula will yield an integer!

Could anyone give a proof of this fact?

Not to prove the formula, just to prove that the value is an integer not merely a rational number.

Comment: I asked the same question some years ago. The answer from an expert was: No, not obvious.